# number from $_GET not being read into simplexml xpath query using php

Tags: php, xpath, get, simplexml

THIS WORKS:

```
1 $number  = 2;
2 $allofit = simplexml_load_file("thexmlfile.xml");
3 $thebook = $allofit -> booklist[$number] -> abook;
4 echo $thebook;
```

THIS FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK: 
But if I want to read $number from a from with method GET I set

```
 6 $number=$_GET[thenumber];   // $number=2 from the form//
 7 echo $number;              // and properly shows $number=2 --*/
 8 $allofit = simplexml_load_file("thexmlfile.xml");
 9 $thebook = $allofit -> booklist[$number] -> abook;
 10 echo $thebook;
```

The echo on line 10 reports nothing (no error, just blank space in the html) even though I can successfully echo $number in line 7... so its being set, but just not picked up in line 9.. although the equivalent in line 3 works (!).

Any ideas folks?

Thanks in advance
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $number=$_GET[thenumber];

At this stage $number is a string.

Do you need to coerce it into an integer? Probably with intval? http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: thanks Mark! Despite agonising over this for 2hours, about 2 minutes after posting I suddenly recalled my FORTRAN days and the way one needs to declare variables!!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$number=intval($_GET[thenumber]);
```

Comment: yep, thanks Shane. Sorry for schoolboy questions. Am new to PHP ... I recalled my FORTRAN days and remembered one needs to declare variables as a  type. intval or (int) doe the trick :) Thaks fo rthe quick response

Answer (score 1):

PHP should convert your "2" to a 2 without a problem. My guess is that you're missing quotes: `$number=$_GET[thenumber]`. Try `$number=$_GET['thenumber'];`

Comment: hi. I am afraid the quotes did not solve the problem (I tried single and double quotes first). The trick was declare $_GET[thenumber] as an integer value thus : intval($_GET[thenumber]). Thanks anyway